# Will two simultaneous read requests have results consistent with each other?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Let's say I have a firestore cloud function that will add one base and one player, in a transaction.

Will the below code always give me the same number of bases as players?

```js
const db = firebase.firestore();
const basesPromise = db.collection("bases").get();
const playersPromise = db.collection("players").get();
Promise.all([basesPromise, playersPromise])
    .then(([bases, players]) => {
      console.log("Bases:", bases);
      console.log("Players:", players);
    });
```

More generally, I'm wondering if when I make two requests at the same time, if the results I get back from them are consistent with each other.

Do those requests hit the server at the same time, and return data consistent with each other?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Firestore gives no guarantees than any two reads will always yield the same values.  It's always possible that something could have changed between them, by transaction or not.  In your code, those two queries are actually not happening "at the same time".  The requests from the client are actually piplined over a single connection in the best possible case.

The only guarantees you get are that modifications to some number of documents made by a single transaction or batch write will all happen atomically.  There is never a partially complete transaction or batch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, is there any way to get a consistent snapshot of the database? Perhaps I should have a cloud function which uses a transaction to read from multiple collections? That wouldn't let me listen though... Maybe I could combine all of my documents into one giant collection at the root?

Comment: I'm reading up more on Firestore's guarantees, and I'm seeing a lot of sources saying it's strongly consistent, such as at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore. So, if I'm understanding you and this correctly, Firestore does have strong consistency, just not across different collections (since there's no API for requesting from multiple collections like I need), is that right?

Comment: Right, there is no API that queries across collections, other than collection group queries.